# How to suggest my application in the list for save pdfs?

Tags: ios, pdf

I am working on an application which I used `pdfkit` to implement that, and it shows and save pdf files.
My problem is that when I receive a pdf file in my email and then I want to save that pdf file in that application, when I click on save button it suggests this page to me but my application is not in the list. How can I make sure that my application also comes in this list as a suggested app?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Refer this link: 
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1587/_index.html.

You need to register the document types that your application can open with iOS. To do this you need to add a document type to your app’s Info.plist for each document type that your app can open. Additionally if any of the document types are not known by iOS, you will need to provide an Uniform Type Identifier (UTI) for that document type.

**Adding A Document Type:**

To add the document type do the following:

In your Xcode project, select the target you want to add the document type to.

1.Select the Info tab.

2.Click on the disclosure button for Document Types to open the document types.

3.Click the “+” button.

In the newly created document type :

4.Type the name of the document type.

5.In the “Types” section fill in the UTI for the new type.

6.Provide an icon for the document.

7.Click the disclosure triangle to open Additional document type properties.

8.Click in the table to add a new key and value.

9.For the key value type: CFBundleTypeRole.

10.For the value type: Editor.

11.Click the + button to add another key/value pair.

12.For the key value type: LSHandlerRank.

13.For the value type: Owner.

**Adding A Custom UTI:**

If the document type you are adding is a custom document type, or a document type that iOS does not already know about, you will need to define the UTI for the document type. To add a new UTI do the following:

In your Xcode project select the target you want to add the new UTI to.
Select the Info tab.

1.Click on the disclosure button for Exported UTIs.

2.Click the “+” button.

3.Select “Add Exported UTI”.

4.In the Description field, fill in a description of the UTI.

5.In the Identifier field, fill in the identifier for the UTI.

6.In the Conforms To field fill in the list of UTIs that this new UTI conforms to.

7.Toggle the “Additional exported UTI properties” disclosure triangle to open up a table where you can add some additional information.

8.Click in the empty table and a list of items that can be added to the table will be displayed.

9.Type in “UTTypeTagSpecification”.

10.Set the type to Dictionary.

11.Click the disclosure triangle to open it, and click the + button in the table row to add an entry.

12.For the “New item” change the name to “public.filename-extension”.

13.For the type of the item change it to “Array”.

14.Toggle open the item you just added and click the + button in the table row.

15.For item 0 change the “value” to the file extension of your document. For example, txt, pdf, docx, etc.

[image]

The easiest way to test your custom document type is to email your custom file to your iOS device. Navigate to the email and ensure that the attachment is there. Tap and hold the document attachment icon. This should open a popover on the iPad, or an action sheet on the iPhone, that shows all of the apps that open your document type. Your app should show up in the list. Tap your app icon and your app should launch and receive the document from the email.

Comment: Don't forget to mention that this is copied from https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1587/_index.html.

Comment: thank you 100...000 times. very helpful. I will check it and if there is any question I will let you know. thank you very very much again.

Comment: Happy Coding :-)

Comment: thank you again that works fine and right now the application is in the list of  suggested apps for me to open with,  when I choose my application it runs correctly but the problem is that it does not show the pdf. I will work on it and for further question I start a new question. any way thank you very much @SuganyaMarlin

Answer (score 2):

You need to create [Action Extension](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/Action.html).

Take a look at [PSPDFKit's article](https://pspdfkit.com/blog/2017/action-extension/).